# Mocking/polyfilling indexedDB

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, indexeddb

I'm writing some unit tests for a module which makes heavy use of indexedDB. In phantomjs many of the tests are failing due to its lack of support for indexedDB.

I've trawled the internet and not managed to find any indexedDB polyfill/mock I can use as a helper for my testsuite. Before I attempt writing one myself, is there a library out there that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two well known open source are [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) and [IndexedDB-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill/) from Facebook.

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/IndexedDB-polyfill is no longer maintained by FB.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an IndexedDB mock for testing an angular service that wraps IndexedDB. i used jasmine/karma for testing.

https://github.com/szimmers/mock-indexeddb

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out my open source library, ydn-db?

I completed polyfill for websql http://dev.yathit.com/blog/indexeddb-polyfill.html

You can mock it using (AVL tree) memory store in the library.

However the library is not IndexedDB polyfill, but rather one-up-abstract level (ORM like) polyfill, due to performance.